# When applying a template, are a creature's saving throws recalculated as its new type if not explicitly mentioned in the template?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, character-templates

Consider two templates, the [ghost](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/ghost) and the [skeleton](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/skeleton).

Both templates explicitly change the resulting creature's type to Undead, and both state the resulting creature "uses all the base creature's statistics and special abilities except as noted here". Regarding saving throws, the ghost template is silent; but, the skeleton template specifically notes:

> **Saves:** Base save bonuses are Fort +1/3 HD, Ref +1/3 HD, and Will +1/2 HD + 2.

These are the exact same saves as are the default for the Undead type. Is the inclusion of this line a redundancy in the rules, or does the absence of that line in the ghost template mean the base saving throws from the base creature are retained?

Using an [Adult Silver Dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/metallic-silver/adult-silver-dragon) as a base creature, the resulting skeleton unambiguously has **Fort** +7, **Ref** +6, **Will** +10; however, the resulting ghost might have either **Fort** +12, **Ref** +7, **Will** +17 if recalculated as the Undead type base saves or **Fort** +17, **Ref** +12, **Will** +17 if recalculated with Dragon type base saves.

Which is it, and why?

Comment: If you find weird that a dragon ghost don't have undead default saves, you can think about the fact [humanoids are supposed to have d8 for HD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/) but a human barbarian would get d12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ghost template specifically says (from the link you provided):

> Type:  The creature's type changes to undead.  Do not recalculate the creature's base attack bonus, saves, or skill points.  It gains the incorporeal subtype.

RAW, the base save doesn't change when the Adult Silver Dragon becomes a ghost.

Comment: Wow. I guess that's a bad example due to hasty reading.

Comment: Eh.  It's caused me to realize that, though it's not mentioned in the ghost template, Charisma is used to calculate the Fortitude saves of all the ghosts, and now I'm trying to track down where it says explicitly to do that.  So congrats on causing me to go chasing off after *that*.

Comment: *There* it is:  Undead creature type.  Curiosity sated.

Comment: I think the clear intention is to use Charisma in place of Constitution wherever Constitution would ordinarily be involved; for example, the Ghost template explicitly notes to use Charisma to calculate a Ghost's special attacks, so the above Adult Silver Dragon's breath weapon would have a Charisma-based DC of ... 25?

Comment: That is darn close to a word-for-word of the description from the undead template, so kudos to you.